# How to implement a UML synchronisation bar in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, synchronization, uml, v8, fork-join

So, Javascript does async very well in that one can pass an event handler function such as in this code taken from this [example](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#user-content-introduction)

```
connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

And I was wondering that if one breaks up one's code into async blocks sometimes you'll want all the strands to wait and regroup/gather, in UML I think this is a [Synchronisation Bar](http://teaching.shu.ac.uk/aces/rh1/elearning/uml/uml_bpm_howto_5.htm) (the thick black solid horizontal rectangles in diagrams 2 & 3)

I was wondering how this looks in Javascript.  In Windows code, one could set Mutex's and Semaphore etc.

So, how to implement a UML synchronisation bar in Javascript please?

Comment: I'm not Java guy, but P/V (semaphore operations) are available in all almost all languages, resp. the provided libraries.

Comment: See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: JavaScript not Java.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian : And notably JavaScript is single threaded (on V8 server) whilst Java is multi-threaded, so your link is inappropriate.

Comment: Doh! I'm really not Java/(Script) guy :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, JavaScript is single-threaded, so there's no need for multi-thread synchronization primitives like Mutexes and Semaphores. One way to think about it is that there's an implicit single global mutex, and every async callback grabs that mutex on entry. Or in plain English: only one function executes at the same time.

So what you'd do is implement similar bookkeeping as a Semaphore does using plain variables, like a global variable counting the number of outstanding async requests. Depending on your code, you can either have every callback check if it's the last one, and trigger the continuation if so; or you can poll the counter periodically (which would be less elegant).

Roughly:

```
var g_semaphore = 0;

function GetCallback(i) {
  return function() {
    console.log("callback #" + i + " coming back");
    /* ... do stuff ... */
    g_semaphore--;
    CheckSyncBar();
  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log("requesting callback #" + i);
  g_semaphore++;
  window.setTimeout(GetCallback(i), Math.random() * 5000);
}

function CheckSyncBar() {
  if (g_semaphore > 0) return;
  window.setTimeout(Continuation, 0);
}

function Continuation() {
  console.log("all callbacks are done, continuing");
  /* ... do stuff ... */
}
```

Comment: Ok, nice, but is there no intrinsic language support for this, I mean C# has Async and Await and an example is given here of multiple requests being gathered https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696703(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Looks like setTimeout is a key technique here but V8 server side has no window.

Comment: setTimeout in my example is just a dead simple stand-in for "anything that sends off callbacks that will be called back later". I'm sure node.js has equivalent functionality. --- "async" and "await" are coming to JavaScript, implementation/spec work is ongoing. There are already Promise objects which you can use to conveniently chain async operations.

Comment: To clarify how it works without setTimeout(): (1) In CheckSyncBar, it's not required, it's just a trick to free up the call stack. For non-huge applications, it's perfectly fine to just call or inline Continuation() from there. (2) in the for-loop, you'd put your connection.query() calls instead (or other actual requests your app wants to make).

Comment: Ok, great example. Also, it seems you have given me the right search words to Google, "setTimeout","Promise","async","await" yields pages like https://gist.github.com/danharper/74a5102363fbd85f6b67 which show the evolution of the relevant language feautures.  Thanks very much.